# Embedding HTML5 content into Facebook wall posts?

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-wall

I have managed to get a custom SWF embedded in Facebook wall posts. This can be done by adding special meta tags to the source code of the linked page. For example the respective source of a YouTube play page for this looks like the following:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="87741124305">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLkk3i4tMQw">
<meta property="og:title" content="Marco Huck vs Hugo Hernan Garay 10. Runde KO">
<meta property="og:description" content="...">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/qLkk3i4tMQw/default.jpg">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/qLkk3i4tMQw?version=3&amp;autohide=1">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="398">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="224">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
```

However, this apparently only works for Flash content.

Recently, Facebook has added support for HTML5 videos originating from YouTube (used for playing video on iPad.) It would be quite interesting to know whether this is limited to YouTube. Does anyone know whether it is possible for the rest of us to embed HTML(5) code into Facebook wall posts? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but there's currently no API to achieve what you suggest. HTML5 is a standard we're committed to though, so I wouldn't rule out this feature possibly being added in the future.

Comment: Colm, thanks for your reply. It would really be sweet to have this!

Comment: Hello @ColmDoyle, is there any progress on that feature, since 2011? It would be quite useful to have it. :)

Comment: any news for now or future plan?

Comment: Bump... Active content in wall posts is becoming more common, would be great to know how.

Comment: I'm not at FB anymore, so I'm not sure what the current status is. Maybe ask at https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers

Comment: How is it working for them? This would be a awsome feature. You could make interactive games and stuff on walls.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible now:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Check the lower part of the page. Just as in the HTML5  tag, you can define various sources now, starting with Flash Player and falling back to MP4 and so on. You'll lose the customized appearance, but at least the video will play.

Answer (score -1):

you can enable using this!

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta property="og:type" content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="260" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="520" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $vtitle ?>" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $vdis ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $vpic ?>" />
<meta property="og:video" content="<?php echo $vlink ?>" />"
```

how ever it is required you also have a standered ssl on your website to post on facebook wall, with flash or html5.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was about embedding HTML5 code as an alternative to Flash-based content on the user's FB wall. Your answer seems to only cover HTML5 videos.