# How to create active all content in Facebook

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api

I have an idea for a holiday wall post where you can poke the fruit cake, similar to poke the rabbit. When it's shared in a Facebook wall post I would users to be able to interact with it before they would share it themselves. I have see active content in wall posts from other sites but reading the documentation, and [one other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6746671/46810), has not been very fruitful. (pun intended). Can anyone share some holiday cheer and help me crack this (chest)nut?

Comment: Great. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What can't you do? Or are you just asking for someone else to write your code?

Comment: I have used graph API to share posts, and none of the other regular or custom meta tags that I can add to the page seem to relate to interactive wall posts. With out the vocabulary of a Facebook app developer I'm stuck plodding through the hundred of ways to share a like or a link to something and not as active content as I expressed in my post. The goal of this is question is solicit information about active posts and from that figure it out my self. Though with out any code posted someone would have to be literally omniscient to "write your code" in their response. Thanks any way though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called "feed gaming" and it´s only possible with swf files (Flash) afaik. Here´s the link to the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/feed-gaming/

Comment: Excellent!!! This is exactly what I was trying to find buried under the pages on how to "share" and "like". I'll dive in to this and see how far I can get. If I figure it out, I'll post more, but you have and will keep the answer. Merry Christmas :-)